# Could not import to Postman

Tags: python, api, ubuntu, postman, debian

When I import a folder in postman it will be an error like following picture
can everybody help me?
[image]

Comment: Do you have access to read that directory?

Answer (score 0):

You have not access to read or modify this directory or file, try it on terminal :

`sudo chmod 777 /media/mohammadjavad/MyDisk`

or try to change permissions manually.